# Where to validate Django AJAX app?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm working on an event based AJAX application using Django. Within my models I've a class that creates and updates an objects and I would like to include better input validation. For example, I know that my start date should be before my end date and would like to check for this fact within the app.

Do I place this within my models? It seems messy to messy to check all 8 input parameters are valid within the creation or save method.

For example, something like this:

```
if foo != '' and int(foo) > 0:
    self.foo = foo
```

I know Django has the functionality to validate forms, but can this also be applied to AJAX streams?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example). It's the docs themselves, so it's always a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this may help: https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation

Documentation:

https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/docs/usage.txt

https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/docs/serving-ajax-validation-media-server.txt